# How to change style of chapter

Tags: chapters

How can I change style of chapter in my thesis report like this:

---

BAB I          -->position in midle top page

INTRODUCE      -->position in midle top page

1.1. Background

```
    {1.5cm}Text...
```

and this is the second line of continuing paragraph.

---

Thank's a lot

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please provide a minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Comment: I try to make a new style for my thesis template. I use fncychap to control my chapter from conny style. But the chapter still shown like this: Bab 1 Introduction. I want it show like as: Bab I Introduction and I.1 Background.

Comment: Right now, the question is highly unclear. Please add more detail and a minimal working example.